# Using userAgent to determine correct download link

Tags: html, windows, macos, operating-system

I've tried to find a simple userAgent scrip that will display a download image that when clicked will download our installer file.

If the user is on a mac, it needs to display the image pointing to install.dmg, where as on windows it needs to point to install.msi, and lastly, windowsxp pointing to install.exe

I understand that using userAgent requests is not the best practice, however our site is only visited by a select group of users who aren't spoofing their agent ID. Most of users are very.. "simple".. most of the time they need assistance turning on their computer.

I found the below script that automatically downloads the file in question, however management here doesn't want it to auto-download, rather, display a download.png that's clickable to download the proper install file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
{
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Win') != -1)
{ window.location.href="resources/install.msi"; }
else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') != -1)
{ window.location.href="resources/install.dmg"; }
else { window.location.href="resources/install.msi"; }
}
// ]]></script>
```

Any ideas? I don't want to have to redirect to a different page for each install, such as having a landing page for Mac users, and a landing page for Windows 8 users, etc. Just display the linked png file that is appropriate for their OS.

I was thinking of a document.write statement, but can't figure out how to display the image that's clickable.

Notes:

- There is no requirement for mobile versions, such as iPhones, etc.
- We're using a Joomla based theme that I've whitelisted the < script > filters.
- This is in a single article, no redirects or anything funky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use document.write to do what you asked. Just put this piece of code whereever you want the download image to be.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    var WINDOWS_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE = "image_win.png";
    var MAC_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE = "image_mac.png";

    var WINDOWS_INSTALLER_FILE = "insall.exe"
    var MAC_INSTALL_FILE = "install.dmg"

    var ua_string = navigator.userAgent;

    if((ua_string.indexOf('Win') != -1){
        //The OS is Windows.
        document.write('<img src="' + WINDOWS_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE + '" href="' + WINDOWS_INSTALLER_FILE + '" />');
    }
    else if(ua_string.indexOf('Mac') != -1){
        //The OS is Mac.
        document.write('<img src="' + MAC_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE + '" href="' + MAC_INSTALLER_FILE + '" />');
    }
    else{
        //Other OS.
        document-write("<h1>Sorry. We don't support your OS.</h1>");
    }
// ]]></script>
```

The variables with capital letters are configuration variables.

**EDIT:**
Sorry. I confused the "()"'s-
    //

```
    var WINDOWS_INSTALLER_FILE = "insall.exe"
    var MAC_INSTALL_FILE = "install.dmg"

    var ua_string = navigator.userAgent;

    if(ua_string.indexOf('Win') != -1){
        //The OS is Windows.
        document.write('<img src="' + WINDOWS_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE + '" href="' + WINDOWS_INSTALLER_FILE + '" />');
    }
    else if(ua_string.indexOf('Mac') != -1){
        //The OS is Mac.
        document.write('<img src="' + MAC_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE + '" href="' + MAC_INSTALLER_FILE + '" />');
    }
    else{
        //Other OS.
        document-write("<h1>Sorry. We don't support your OS.</h1>");
    }
// ]]></script>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    var WINDOWS_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE = "image_win.png";
    var MAC_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE = "image_mac.png";

    var WINDOWS_INSTALLER_FILE = "insall.exe"
    var MAC_INSTALLER_FILE = "install.dmg"

    var ua_string = navigator.userAgent;

    if(ua_string.indexOf('Win') != -1){
        //The OS is Windows.
        document.write('<a href="' + WINDOWS_INSTALLER_FILE + '"><img src="' + WINDOWS_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE + '"/></a>');
    }
    else if(ua_string.indexOf('Mac') != -1){
        //The OS is Mac.
        document.write('<a href="' + MAC_INSTALLER_FILE + '"><img src="' + MAC_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE + '"/></a>');
    }
    else{
        //Other OS.
        document-write("<h1>Sorry. We don't support your OS.</h1>");
    }
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: I've tried this code on the page, and it doesn't seem to be working. I've replaced the image_win.png and others with the proper URL's, and I confirmed they're working by manually typing them into the browser, however no download image is showing up? Link to the page  in question here: http://www.candata.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=167

Comment: Could I not eliminate the var section for identifying the images/files, and just specify the urls to the images/files manually? They'll never change. Just keep the if/else statements (and the var for ua_string)?

Comment: I found the problem. Just give me a moment. :)

Comment: Oh, I'm glad it did. I'm on a guest machine and can't test my code.

Comment: Thanks - Got it working. Figures that once my boss saw the updated and working code, that he decided to completely go the other way, and decide to have two static pages for mac and windows, that will need a redirect script, essentially making your hard work now useless to me.. Thanks anyway :)